# bind to xaml or viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, xaml

when I want to have to controls interact should they interact directly through xaml or using the view model?

for example I have two text boxes and the requirement is that A and B display the same text

```
<TextBox Name = "A" Text = "{Binding ViewModel.MyText}"/>
<TextBox Name = "B" Text = "{Binding ViewModel.MyText}"/>
```

is it better to write?

```
<TextBox Name = "A" Text = "{Binding ViewModel.MyText}"/>
<TextBox Name = "B" Text = "{Binding ElementName = A, Path = Text"/>
```

this is of course the simplest case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's completely opinion based. If I would have to do that I would prefer **second approach (binding with elementName)** for following reasons:

1. If both TextBoxes have to be in sync always. Consider scenario where somehow *binding gets broken*, even in that case *both textBoxes will be in sync*.
2. If property name updated then I have *less places in XAML to go and update* (Obviously not major point but just to list down the reasons. It's one of them).
3. Third, if `Name` property containing class is not implementing INPC, even than two textBoxes will be in sync. Can read more about [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/17/puff-the-magic-poco-binding-and-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf).

Rest completely up to you since both approaches are fine.